# changing stack order of jQuery UI modal dialogs

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

I'm popping up two jQuery UI modal dialogs. One of them is triggered on the success of an AJAX function, so it usually comes up later, on top of the first dialog. I'd like to programmatically switch the stacking order of the two dialogs so that the first appears on top of the second. Trying to do this with the zIndex property and with dialog("moveToTop"), but neither seem to be having an effect. Suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

I realized a sample that should work for you: http://jsfiddle.net/kUYcw/.

In this example, if you remove the `stack:false` and `stack:true` options, the dialog `d2` (second one) will appear first.

But, in the example I put in the link, you can see that I forced jQuery to display `d1` first.

**EDIT:**

I've just updated the code. You can find it here: http://jsfiddle.net/DQYEW/3/.

As you can see, the dialog `d2` will show when `d1` calls the close event.

Regards.

Comment: Great, thank you for mentioning the stack option. Also, I have never seen jsfiddle.net before--very useful.

But this does not seem to work when there is a delay: http://jsfiddle.net/DQYEW/ Note that I am delaying the second dialog by a second to simulate how long it takes to run the AJAX query. Do you have any ideas of how to make this work?

Answer (score 1):

Based on Zakaria's post, I think Drew meant this:
http://jsfiddle.net/pinusnegra/KqK6n/